# Poner una imagen utillizando la libreria PHPEXCEL

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

estoy intentando poner una imagen de encabezado en mi documento EXCEL pero no lo he logrado, estoy utilizando la librería PHPEXCEL y el framework CODEIGNITER.

Espero que me puedan ayudar, les comparto mi código cuando genero el EXCEL.

```
public function export_excel_calls() {
  $fechas = $this->session->flashdata('fechas');
  //echo($fechas['date_inicio']);
  //print_r($fechas['date_inicio']);
  //Exportar excel
    $llamadas = $this->reg_calls_model->todas_calls($fechas['date_inicio'], $fechas['date_fin']);
    //print_r($llamadas);

    // if(!empty($llamadas)){
    //Cargamos la librería de excel.
    $this->load->library('excel'); 
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Llamadas');
    //Contador de filas
    $contador = 1;
    //Contador de registros
    $contador1 = 1;
    //$contador_row = 0;
    //Le aplicamos ancho las columnas.
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(15);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(10);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(20);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(10);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(15);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(15);
    //Le aplicamos negrita a los títulos de la cabecera.
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A{$contador}")->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("B{$contador}")->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("C{$contador}")->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("D{$contador}")->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("E{$contador}")->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F{$contador}")->getFont()->setBold(true);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("G{$contador}")->getFont()->setBold(true);
    //Definimos los títulos de la cabecera.
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A{$contador}", 'No');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("B{$contador}", 'Destino');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C{$contador}", 'Origen');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("D{$contador}", 'Fecha');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("E{$contador}", 'Duración');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("F{$contador}", 'Estado');

    //Definimos la data del cuerpo.        
    foreach($llamadas as $l){
       //Incrementamos una fila más, para ir a la siguiente.
      $contador++;
       //Informacion de las filas de la consulta.
      $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A{$contador}", $contador1);
      $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("B{$contador}", $l->src);
      $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C{$contador}", $l->dst);
      $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("D{$contador}", $l->calldate);
      $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("E{$contador}", $l->billsec);
      $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("F{$contador}", $l->disposition);
      $contador1++;

    }

    //Le ponemos un nombre al archivo que se va a generar.
    $archivo = 'Reporte-'.time().'.xls';
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$archivo.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
    //Hacemos una salida al navegador con el archivo Excel.
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
 // }else{
 //    redirect('login_controller/perfil_calls', 'refresh');      
 // }
}
```

Comment: PHPExcel está obsoleto y no es recomendable su uso, mejor usa PhpSpreedSheet https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: OK muchas gracias